# Marketing Cloud FTP Disablement

Tags: marketing-cloud

as per the recent update the Salesforce is going to stop the FTP protocol support! 
But, below is what I understand,

- The FTP location and folder structure remain same.
- All the existing Import and export behavior from within Marketing cloud, like Import activity remain same.
- We will still be able to access it via FileZilla [Correct me if I am wrong!]
- I hope if there are any external application accessing the FTP location using FTP protocol, then those needs to change to use SFTP.

Finally, my question is what an all steps should I follow/perform checks (apart from the above specified) so the current Marketing cloud setup is NOT affected after this change!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This only applies to the unsecure FTP protocol on port 21. You should be fine if you are currently using SFTP on port 22. I have not been able to even use FTP on any of the newer instances, as this is a legacy feature.

In your FTP client, ensure you select SFTP option, as in my Cyberduck client below:
[image]

Also ensure, that any integrations using SFMC Enhanced FTP to send/receive data, also use this protocol.

Anything else around Enhanced FTP remains exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks @Lukas Lunow ... :)